# Deleting a | from a Linux cmmand

Tags: linux, sed

cat linux |sed 's/Windows/Linux/g' >linux_corrige

Is there a way to do this in only 1 command without the | ? I tried to find a way to go inside "linux" with sed but couldn't find it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/Windows/Linux/g' linux >linux_corrige
```

See [man sed](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) for lots more info. The general syntax of the command is near the top:

```
sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
```

The explanation of "{script-only-if-no-other-script}" is lower down, after the description of the possible `OPTION`s:

> If no `-e`, `--expression`, `-f`, or `--file` option is given, then the first non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are specified, then the standard input is read.